# PiBeacons: iPhone find BLE UUID not iBeacon

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspbian, ibeacon, hci

i'm sorry for my english but i have a problem with PiBeacon.

I have a Raspberry Pi and a Usb dongle Sitecom CN-524.

I read and I follow this tutorial ( http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/09/how-to-make-an-ibeacon-out-of-a-raspberry-pi.html ) and my PiBeacon doesn't works.

I have a iPhone 5 ver 7.1 and with many BLE Utility i find the PiBeacon usb dongle with a UUID different that the UUID assegnated with `sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 bla bla` command.

Why mw usb dongle doesn't record the new UUID?

Thanks you very very much!

Comment: What UUID are you trying to set on the Pi?  What exact utility are you using to see the iBeacon on your iPhone?  You must use an iBeacon utility on your phone like Locate for iBeacon.  And you must configure the iBeacon utility with the same UUID as on the Pi for the iBeacon to be visible.

Comment: Thanks for reply.

I use this command: `$ sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1e 02 01 1a 1a ff 4c 00 02 15 e2 c5 6d b5 df fb 48 d2 b0 60 d0 f5 a7 10 96 e0 00 00 00 00 c5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` for Profile UUID E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0.

I use BLE Utility and BLE Finder and the UUID work with this command `$ sudo hciconfig hci0 leadv` but is 55150126-28a5-6c36-77e4-963db95d37ca not E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0

and with APP Locate iB, Estimote, AirBeacon and another app my PiBeacon doesn't show with any UUID:(

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see iBeacon Proximity UUIDs using a Bluetooth scanning utility like BLE Utility or BLE Finder.  These tools will report a completely different UUID that has nothing to do with the iBeacon Proximity UUID configured on the Pi.

Try using [Locate for iBeacon](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-for-ibeacon/id738709014?mt=8) and make sure any UUID you program into the Pi is also configured in Locate for iBeacon.

Comment: this is the code of my rasperry pi:

$ sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1e 02 01 1a 1a ff 4c 00 02 15 e2 c5 6d b5 df fb 48 d2 b0 60 d0 f5 a7 10 96 e0 00 00 00 00 c5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
< HCI Command: ogf 0x08, ocf 0x0008, plen 44
  1E 02 01 1A 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 E2 C5 6D B5 DF FB 48 D2 B0 60 
  D0 F5 A7 10 96 E0 00 00 00 00 C5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 
> HCI Event: 0x0e plen 4
  01 08 20 12 `

after i do `noscan` and `leadv 3` command.

I add in Locate for iBeacon this UUID:E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0

Major: 0 - Minor: 0 - Power: blank

thanks